# Can't get target from triple

Tags: c#, compilation, llvm, llvm-ir, target-platform

LLVM can't find target from triple. My system's default triple is "i686-pc-win32" (I've tried changing it to "i686-pc-windows-msvc" but it still didn't work).

I couldn't really think/find much about changing the triple, everywhere I looked it seemed that people who had this issue resolved it over 5 years ago by simply changing the triple but for some reason it won't work for me.

Besides changing the triple I also made sure to verify the module (which is alright) and when I call the `LLVM.PrintModuleToFile()` function, it prints it all right (and then I can use llc and clang to link it against a .cpp file, but then I get a different error, namely "A.obj : fatal error LNK1143: invalid or corrupt file: no symbol for COMDAT section 0x5").

```cs
var targetTriple = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(LLVM.GetDefaultTargetTriple());
//targetTriple = "i686-pc-windows-msvc";

if (LLVM.GetTargetTriple(targetTriple, out var target, out var err)) {
    Console.WriteLine(err);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

When running this code, the if body is entered and the following error is displayed: "No available targets are compatible with this triple."

Thanks for any help in advance!